# How can 'but' mean 'not'?

Tags: conjunctions, legalese

<sub>Primary Source: Benjamin N. Cardozo; *Nature of the Judicial Process* (1921).

Secondary Source: Lief H. Carter, Thomas F. Burke; [*Reason in Law* (9 ed 2016)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/022632818X), p. vii (before the Table of Contents).</sub>

> What is it that I do when I decide a case? To what sources of information do 
>   I appeal for guidance? In what proportions do I permit them to contribute to the 
>   result? In what proportions ought they to contribute? If a precedent is applicable, 
>   when do I refuse to follow it? If no precedent is applicable, how do I reach the rule 
>   that will make a precedent for the future? If I am seeking logical consistency, the 
>   symmetry of the legal structure, how far shall I seek it? At what point shall the quest 
>   be halted by some discrepant custom, by some consideration of the social wel- 
>   fare, by my own or the common standards of justice and morals? Into that strange 
>   compound which is brewed daily in the caldron of the courts, all these ingredients 
>   enter in varying proportions. I am not concerned to inquire whether judges ought 
>   to be allowed to brew such a compound at all. I take judge-made law as one of the 
>   existing realities of life. There, before us, is the brew. **[1.] Not** a judge on the bench **but** 
>   has had a hand in the making.

The context implies 1 to mean:

2. Not a judge on the bench has NOT had a hand in the making [of law].
   = 3. Every such judge has had such a hand.

But comparing 1 with 2 evokes this  question: how does **but** mean NOT?
The above published in 1921, I recognise this syntax's possible obsolescence.

P.S.: The polyfunctionality of 'but' has troubled me: [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/239860/50720), [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/12676/5306).

Comment: Here is my obligatory comment that it does because it does, and one will make much more progress by simply accepting and internalizing it than through hand-wringing over how the uncountable interactions of speakers throughout centuries has landed the language in such a state of affairs. To repeat my favorite analogy: "How come that tree has 78 branches?" "Because that's how many it grew". Having got that off my chest once again, I'll leave the etymological sleuthing to others.

Comment: I think it has brings the effect of negation with it in many sentences but is not directly substitutable with the word ***not***.

Comment: I might rephrase your statement as: “There isn’t a judge on the bench ***that*** has***n’t*** had a had in the making.”

Comment: There is no (=*Not a*) judge on the bunch except (=*but*) [he who] has had a hand in the making → Every judge on the bench has had a hand in the making.

Comment: It doesn't really mean _but_. The meaning is closer to _except_ or _without_: there is not a judge on the beach but [= except] those who have had a hand in the making. (Edit: Jinx, @StoneyB!)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "Except" is one of the ordinary meanings of *but*: "Every man but one escaped".

Comment: @StoneyB Both _except_ and _without_ are among the ordinary meanings of _but_; this _but_ here is close in meaning to both, but not (to my mind) entirely identical. (Gah! My previous comment was supposed to say, “It doesn't really mean _not_”! It does of course mean _but_.)

Comment: "judge on the bunch" and "judge on the beach" from two of my favorite commenters? It's a great morning for typos. :-)

Comment: [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/but) lists the sense, but could do better at explaining it: << but  ... conj.
...
7. That ... not. Used after a negative or question:  _There never is a tax law presented but someone will oppose it._ >> 'There is never a tax law presented that someone won't oppose' cf 'There is not one judge on the bench that has not had a hand in the making'. I'd say it's an archaic usage.

Comment: @MarkHubbard Evidently! :-D (I figured those poor judges deserved some sunny time.)

Comment: "None but the brave deserve the fair" (Dryden). 'But' doesn't mean 'not'. 'None but' means 'only', 'not a... but' means 'all of them'.

Answer (score 2):

*Not a(n) X but Y* is an obsolescent expression meaning *every X Y*.

The original meaning of "but" is "outside", and in most of its meanings it has some sort of negative force. But (!) only in this construction (I think)  does it act as a negator on a clause.

It seems to be covered in the OED entry under meaning 12: "With general sense ‘that not’, Latin *quin*. After negative and questioning constructions."

12a is: "a. In a simple attributive clause belonging to a n. or pronoun in the main sentence: That..not.", example (1846):

> Hardly a man passes by but he must add a wreath to it.

12b. is "With omission of the pronominal subject or object of the subord. clause, so that but acts as a negative relative: That..not, who..not. (Latin *quin*.)", and I think the example from Keats, 1820, is parallel with the one in the question:

> Not a man but felt the terror in his hair.